# Search through Object Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I am having an javascript array with objects in it:

```
var array;
array[{name: "Peter",class: "7"},{name: "Klaus",class: "3"}];
```

How to find out if in this array is the name Peter?

EDIT: I want to have something like this

```
if (array.find("Peter"))
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: By iterating through the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

```
arr.find(row => row.name === 'Peter');
```

Don't forget to use the polyfill in the link if your targeted browsers don't support this method.

Answer (score 1):

```
var array = [{name: "Peter",class: "7"},
             {name: "Klaus",class: "3"}];

var filtered = array.filter(function(item){
    return item.name == 'Peter';
});

// filtered now equals [{name: "Peter",class: "7"}]
```

Comment: Nice solution! I've always just seen iterating solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First you should correct your array declaration

```
var array = [{name: "Peter",class: "7"},{name: "Klaus",class: "3"}];
```

And you should try it

```
array.find(function(o) { return o.name==="Klaus" })
```

Hope this help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var students = [{name: "Peter", class: "7"}, {name: "Klaus", class: "3"}];
students.find( student => { return student.name === 'Peter' });

function find(arr, key, value) {
    return arr.find( item => {
        return item[key] === value;
    }) !== undefined;
}


console.log(find(students, 'name', 'Peter'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Some sample code in both ES6 and ES5!

```
// Search for "Peter" in the name field
if (arr.find(row => row.name === 'Peter')) {
    console.log('found');
} else {
    console.log('not found');
}

// Same function in ES5
arr.find(function(row) {
    console.log(row);
    if (row.name === 'Peter') {
    console.log('ES5: found');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
array.findIndex(e => e['name'] === 'Peter')
```

One of AngularJS solutions